# Does restarting WhatsApp docker containers invalidate existing authentication/Bearer tokens?

Tags: whatsapp

I want to know whether restarting the WhatsApp docker containers, or killing old ones and getting new ones up and running cause the existing authentication tokens to invalidate/stop working. Do I have to fetch new tokens every time there is some deployment of the WhatsApp containers ?

Comment: Which WhatsApp docker containers do you mean?

Comment: @FrankGroeneveld https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/client-architecture/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a reply from WhatsApp API support team. The authentication tokens are still valid after redeployment of WhatsApp docker containers.
https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/1138101296601972/?post_id=1138101299935305